# Convert 32 bit network order to host in C

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to convert a uint32_t from network byte order to host format. I'm reading from a tcp connection 4 bytes that I store in the buffer like this:

```
ssize_t read = 0;
char *file_buf;
size_t fb_size = 4 * sizeof(char);
file_buf = malloc(fb_size);
read = recv(socket_file_descriptor,file_buf,fb_size,0);
```

so I store the number in file_buf but I want a number, how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks straightforward:

```
ssize_t read = 0;
uint32_t myInteger;  // Declare a 32-bit uint.

// Pass a pointer to the integer, and the size of the integer.
read = recv(socket_file_descriptor,&myInteger,sizeof(myInteger),0);

myInteger = ntohl(myInteger); // Change from Network order to Host order.
```

Comment: it seems to not work I expected a value of 300 but it gives me 2130771968

Comment: The value you cited is `0x7F010000`.  The value `300`, in hex is: `0x12C`.  They have no relation.   `0x017F` is decimal `383`, which would imply you may be working with 16-bit values, not 32 bit values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it.  Note the use of `ntohl()` to convert the data from network-endian to host-endian form:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

[...]

char file_buf[4];
if (recv(socket_file_descriptor,file_buf,fb_size,0) == sizeof(file_buf))
{
   uint32_t * p = (uint32_t *) file_buf;
   uint32_t num = ntohl(*p);
   printf("The number is %u\n", num);
}
else printf("Short read or network error?\n");
```

Comment: It may not make a difference in practice, but semantically, don't you want `ntohl()` instead of `htonl()`?

Answer (score 1):

Some OSes (Linux with glibc, BSDs) have [size-specific](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/endian.3.html) endianness conversion functions too, to supplement `ntohl()` and `ntohs()`.

```
#include <endian.h> // Might need <sys/endian.h> instead on some BSDs

void your_function(uint32_t bigend_int) {
  uint32_t host_int = be32toh(bigend_int);
}
```

---

Edit:

But since you seem to have easy access to the individual bytes, there's always Rob Pike's [preferred approach](https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html):

```
uint32_t host_int = (file_buf[3]<<0) | (file_buf[2]<<8) | (file_buf[1]<<16) | (file_buf[0]<<24);
```

Comment: [Per POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/htonl.html), `ntohl()` is specifically for 32-bit values and `ntohs()` is specifically for 16-bit values.